# HTML automatically closing tags when using ajax to build template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, templates

So I am trying to make a template using HTML and jQuery AJAX. The problem that I am running to is HTML is automatically closing tags prior to receiving my closing tags so it messes up my format i need to know more info about this or a better way to do this

JavaScript

```
$.post( "https://url.com/header.php", function(data){
    $( "#header" ).after(data);
});

$.post( "https://url.com/footer.php", function(data){
    $( "#footer" ).before(data);
});
```

This is the opening tag in the #header file that I'm pulling from server

```
<div class='container-fixed'>
```

This is closing tag my #footer file that im pulling from the server

```
</div>
```

Than I have my home.html file which is my template page with my #header,#footer

```
<header id='header'></header>

<div>HELLO WORLD</div>

<footer id='header'></footer>
```

This is how I want my final code to look after header and footer has loaded

```
<div class='container-fixed'>

<div>HELLO WORLD</div>

</div>
```

But this is what is actually happening

```
<div class='container-fixed'>
</div>

<div>HELLO WORLD</div>
```

The browser is not wrapping my code in the container file, it just closes my container div on its own than it just deletes my closing tag in footer file. My code is way more complex than what I'm using in this example, but I'm just trying to keep it simple; I know that I can add the container div to my home.html but that's not what I'm trying to do. Any workaround? Thanks

My question is how can I send and unclosed tag in 1 file and close it in the other without browser doing it for me.

Comment: Don't append to the DOM until you have all the html

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("container-fixed")[0].children[0].innerHTML = "HELLO WORLD + whatever!!"`

Comment: @patrick how do i do that in my situation?

Comment: @cryptopat thats just inserting the hello world , im building a template so there is way more content than hello world i have to use that container div to wrap all my pages

Comment: I feel like you are going about this backwards.  Rather than dynamically loading the header and footer part, which you just said should wrap all your pages, that part should be loaded on page load and the inner content, HELLO WORLD in this case, would be loaded dynamically.  As it is you are creating a lot more work for yourself than this should require.

Comment: It's a hassle (and not a good practice) to spread opening and closing tags across multiple files. Even if you want to have separate files for each `header`, `content`, and `footer`, make a base template file which includes these three (or more if needed) files and each of the file has its own neat and complete code with each file opening and closing its own tags within itself. That makes life easier for development, maintenance, and scaling.

Comment: @taplar i see what your saying but my code is way more complex than what i used in this example and i have way more tags that  opened in header file that needs to be closed in the footer file,  if have 100 pages on this website i would have to change each file for one edit if load these type of tags in the main page , thats what i was trying to avoid

Comment: Templating like this is only going to add more complexity, not reduce it.

Comment: @xuhaib can you give me an example in answer please so i can understand more the better way your saying please...what your saying is what im trying to do i just dont know how

Comment: im not that good with templates i only really know how to do templates while using a server language like php,  but in this case im trying to template using html css and javascript alone

Comment: The problem is the purpose of html is to describe the page for the DOM.  The browser uses the html to know what objects to create, what the properties are on those elements, and what their children are.  There is no closing tag in the DOM.  There are only elements.  A closing tag in html is simply the html markup way to signify that nothing after that point belongs to the element it just created.  Also what xuhaib suggested is the same thing I am suggested, just phrased differently.

Comment: @taplar ooohhh that makes alot of sense now thanks for that info, so you suggest i just add the code to every page and go thru the editing of every page if i needed, im thinking thats what ill do i was just hoping i can kind of cheat around it

Comment: The page you load at the start should have your header and footer logic.  The part that is the same for all your 100 pages.  Then you dynamically load the inner content that is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a hassle (and not a good practice) to spread opening and closing tags across multiple files. Even if you want to have separate files for each header, content, and footer, make a base template file which includes these three (or more if needed) files and each of the file has its own neat and complete code with each file opening and closing its own tags within itself. That makes life easier for development, maintenance, and scaling.

Below is a sample layout for a base template file:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <!-- include HEAD file here (meta tags, styles, js/css files etc.) -->
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="container">
         <header>
             <!-- include/display HEADER file here -->
         </header>

         <nav>
             <!-- include/display NAV/MENU file here -->
         </nav>

         <div id="content">
             <!-- include/display CONTENT here -->
         </div>

         <footer>
             <!-- include FOOTER file here -->
         </footer>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can add or remove individual modules (files) as per your requirements.

In my opinion, this approach will be most suited to you since you are trying to build the template through ajax, so you can easily keep all files separate and then include them as and when you need them. You can also have some files included by default (on page load) and include others dynamically through ajax. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: thanks man i see what your saying now yes this way is mucch much easier